# Where did the Wikipedia solution to the Snub Dodecahedron originate?

Tags: polynomials, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, plane-geometry, golden-ratio

In May 2020, Wikipedia changed their [Snub Dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snub_dodecahedron) page, including redefining Xi as a new constant Eta. In 1985, I found an [alternate solution](https://archive.org/details/archimedeanplatonicsolids/mode/2up) that also uses Phi (Golden Ratio), and Eta. Here are both solutions.

$$\text{Wikipedia's Snub Dodecahedron volume =}\; \frac{12\color{Crimson}{\eta^2}\color{Black}{(3}\color{DarkGoldenrod}{\varphi}
\color{Black}{+1)-}\color{Crimson}{\eta}
\color{Black}{(36}\color{DarkGoldenrod}{\varphi}
\color{Black}{+7)-(53}\color{DarkGoldenrod}{\varphi}
\color{Black}{+6)}}{6\sqrt{(3-\color{Crimson}{\eta^2}\color{black}{)^3}}}
$$

$$
\text{Alternate solution =}\;
\frac{10\color{DarkGoldenrod}{\varphi}}{3}\sqrt{ \color{DarkGoldenrod}{\varphi^2}
\color{Black}{+3}\color{Crimson}{\eta}
\color{Black}{(}\color{DarkGoldenrod}{\varphi}
\color{Black}{+}\color{Crimson}{\eta}
\color{Black}{)}}
\,+\,\frac{\color{DarkGoldenrod}{\varphi^2}}{2}\sqrt{ 5 + 5\sqrt{5}\color{DarkGoldenrod}{\varphi}\color{Crimson}{\eta}
\color{Black}{(}\color{DarkGoldenrod}{\varphi}
\color{Black}{+}\color{Crimson}{\eta}
\color{Black}{)}}
$$

$$
\text{where } \color{Crimson}{Eta}\text{ is defined as:} \quad
\color{Crimson}{\eta\,\equiv\,
\sqrt[3]{ \frac{
\color{DarkGoldenrod}{\varphi}
\color{Crimson}{}}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{
\color{DarkGoldenrod}{\varphi}
\color{Crimson}{-}\frac{5}{27}}}\;+\;}
\color{Crimson}{
\sqrt[3]{ \frac{
\color{DarkGoldenrod}{\varphi}
\color{Crimson}{}}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{
\color{DarkGoldenrod}{\varphi}
\color{Crimson}{-}\frac{5}{27}}}}
$$

Both expressions are the same number, 37.616649962733362975777..., as shown in this [Wolfram Cloud Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/MathMusing/Published/Snub_Dodecahedron.nb). None of the Wikipedia talk notes seem to make reference to where their solution originates?

Comment: wow, had no idea it was possible to do color in mathjax!! very cool

Comment: The solution was added in [this edit](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Snub_dodecahedron&diff=prev&oldid=392009113) on 21 October 2010 by an anonymous editor in Bielefeld, Germany. They commented "closed formula for volume and surface area added" with no other explanation. The same formula appears in https://rechneronline.de/pi/snub-dodecahedron.php , but I can't tell which came first.

Comment: Thanks Chris, yes the 21 October 2010 revision is a bit of a mystery!  Thanks Atticus, color in mathjax is way cool!

Comment: Wikipedia's volume has been update, looks great! here's the [Jupyter](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/archive.org/download/musing_math/Volume_Solutions_To_Snub_Dodecahedron.ipynb)